# Updating location data on Android screen

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gps

I want update location data on Android screen.
I have LocationListener and LocationManager in  **LiczydloGPS.class** :

```
package com.zoltrix.gpsallinfo;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;

public class LiczydloGPS extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private final Context mContext;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude

    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public LiczydloGPS(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // no network provider is enabled
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                // First get location from Network Provider
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        if(location!=null)
        {
        MainActivity main2 = new MainActivity();

        main2.update(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        }
        Log.d("onLocationChanged", "idze do maina");
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     * */
    public double getLatitude() {
        if (location != null) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     * */
    public double getLongitude() {
        if (location != null) {
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to check if best network provider
     * 
     * @return boolean
     * */
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    /**
     * Function to show settings alert dialog
     * */
    public void showSettingsAlert() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog
                .setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        // Setting Icon to Dialog
        // alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.delete);

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        mContext.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }
    /**
     * Stop using GPS listener
     * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
     * */
    public void stopUsingGPS(){
        if(locationManager != null){
            locationManager.removeUpdates(LiczydloGPS.this);
        }       
    }
}
```

In MainActivity i made  method **update** which is called in **LiczydloGPS.class** in **onLocationChanged**:

```
    package com.zoltrix.gpsallinfo;

import com.zoltrix.gpsallinfo.R.id;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    double lat, lon;
    TextView latData, longData;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        latData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latData);
        longData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longData);

        LiczydloGPS gps = new LiczydloGPS(this);

        if (gps.canGetLocation() != true) {
            gps.showSettingsAlert();

        } else {

            lat = gps.getLatitude(); // returns latitude
            lon = gps.getLongitude();
            latData.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
            longData.setText(String.valueOf(lon));

        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case id.oprogramie:

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Oprogramie.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        case id.action_settings:
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, Ustawienia.class);
            startActivity(intent2);
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void update(double lat1, double lon1) {
        Log.d("onLocationChanged", "jest w mainie!");
         latData.setText(lat1);
         longData.setText(lon1);

        Log.d("onLocationChanged", String.valueOf(lat1));
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TOAST!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }



}
```

But when you want to change the GPS data in the DDMS, the application is killed. LOGS:

> 11-11 09:22:27.626: D/GPS Enabled(2734): GPS Enabled 11-11
>   09:22:28.136: D/gralloc_goldfish(2734): Emulator without GPU emulation
>   detected. 11-11 09:22:32.506: D/onLocationChanged(2734): jest w
>   mainie! 11-11 09:22:32.506: D/AndroidRuntime(2734): Shutting down VM
>   11-11 09:22:32.506: W/dalvikvm(2734): threadid=1: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0xb3aa2b90) 11-11 09:22:32.516:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(2734): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 11-11 09:22:32.516:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(2734): Process: com.zoltrix.gpsallinfo, PID: 2734
>   11-11 09:22:32.516: E/AndroidRuntime(2734):
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 11-11 09:22:32.516:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(2734):   at
>   com.zoltrix.gpsallinfo.MainActivity.update(MainActivity.java:69) 11-11
>   09:22:32.516: E/AndroidRuntime(2734):     at
>   com.zoltrix.gpsallinfo.LiczydloGPS.onLocationChanged(LiczydloGPS.java:113)
>   11-11 09:22:32.516: E/AndroidRuntime(2734):   at
>   android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:279)
>   11-11 09:22:32.516: E/AndroidRuntime(2734):   at
>   android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:208)
>   11-11 09:22:32.516: E/AndroidRuntime(2734):   at
>   android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:224)
>   11-11 09:22:32.516: E/AndroidRuntime(2734):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 11-11
>   09:22:32.516: E/AndroidRuntime(2734):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 11-11 09:22:32.516:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(2734):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998) 11-11
>   09:22:32.516: E/AndroidRuntime(2734):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 11-11
>   09:22:32.516: E/AndroidRuntime(2734):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 11-11 09:22:32.516:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(2734):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
>   11-11 09:22:32.516: E/AndroidRuntime(2734):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593) 11-11
>   09:22:32.516: E/AndroidRuntime(2734):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

**Thanks in advance for your help**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get your lat and long insdie onLocationChanged() something like this.

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if(location!=null)
    {
update(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    }
}
```

Comment: I still have NullPointerException :( ,Discovered that everything goes well until the update () change TextView latData longData . Why can not I change the value of the TextView in the method update ()?

Comment: I tried to add a simple toast in the method update (), and even then jumped out the error.

Comment: are you sure you could instantiate a activty?

Comment: I add only Log.d("onLocationChanged", String.valueOf(lat1)); to update(). and lat1 shows only on start ,when I change the GPS data in DDMS there is no display  lat1 in the log, and any errors. :/

Comment: I dont see where do you invoke update() in your activity, the code in optionmenu(..)  supposed to be inside oncreate()..I have not clue why you choose this approach.

Comment: I invoke update() in onLocationChanged , and  fixed bug with oncreate() earlier . I update main post.

Comment: try to Log.d(..) inside onLocationChanged,if you succeeded then use  intent to pass lat and long. I dont think you could instantiate an android activty in a service. and also you are invoking service as function call which is a bad practise.

Comment: In that case, should I do everything in one class?
Is not there a way to "location manger" was in a different class and sends the current GPS data to  TextView  in MainActivity?

Comment: No, All you need to implement observer pattern.. which is very simple.  google it you will find lot of infos..

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Implementing the Observer Pattern will take me some time.

Comment: Here is the observer pattern interface implementation, Hope it saves some time  :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508828/how-to-return-data-in-android-locationlistener?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `NullPointerException` because you are not initializing your TextView in `onCreate()` method. You are initializing them on `onCreateOptionsMenu()` which is wrong,

Modify your code as below,

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        latData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latData);
        longData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longData);
    }
```

Comment: I I fixed this stupid mistake, but I still have `NullPointerException` :( , my new MainActivity :http://pastebin.com/ydjCZ6Pz

Comment: Discovered that everything goes well until the update () change TextView latData longData . Why can not I change the value of the TextView in the method update ()?